# Accessing all Facebook Like buttons on a page using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to write a script that can access all instances of the a Facebook Like button on a webpage using jQuery dynamically, but am having trouble figuring out the correct selector.

The context of the like button could either be on the Facebook website:

```
<span><a href="#" role="button" aria-live="polite" title="Like this" data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;&gt;&quot;}" class="UFILikeLink" id=".reactRoot[0]">Like</a></span>
```

or a third party website (where the like button appears to be embedded inside of a iFrame:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FLike-Button%2F122072747813316&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=1040&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:1020px; height:35px; margin-left: 10px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

With the latter, I'm assuming I need to access the iframe that has a src property equal to the FB like url first (i.e. http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?).

I would like to change the background color of every Like button. How could I find each instance of a like button either in the context of Facebook or on a third party site?

Answer (score 0):

What You are trying to do is restricted by facebook branding guidelines and terms of use.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/branding/

Comment: in a perfect world though, how could this be achieved?